# How should I populate the page heading in my Sitemesh 3 template?

Tags: spring-mvc, freemarker, sitemesh

I'm using Sitemesh 3 and Freemarker with my Spring MVC application.
Freemarker page output is passed to Sitemesh for application of a JSP decorator (will be FTL once I get my config sorted out - I have another SO question about that - as yet unanswered).

I'd got Sitemesh 3 applying the body to the template correctly, now I'd like to add to my setup so an FTL view can set a property that would be rendered in the page heading.

Sitemesh (JSP) template/decorator - this is producing correct output, except for the variable content heading:

```
    <div id="mainWrapper">
    <div id="content">
        <div id="contentheading"><sitemesh:write property="page.heading"></sitemesh:write></div>
        <div>
            <sitemesh:write property='body'/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What do I need to do in my .ftl in order to create some property that would be rendered in the div#contentheading element?

I have a Java config for sitemesh using a custom filter implementation:

```
public class SitemeshFilter extends ConfigurableSiteMeshFilter {
@Override
protected void applyCustomConfiguration(SiteMeshFilterBuilder builder) {
    builder.setMimeTypes("text/html", "application/xhtml+xml");
    builder.addDecoratorPath("/*", "/WEB-INF/templates/page.jsp");
  }
}
```

**Please note I am using Sitemesh 3**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to do this, that requires no additional SiteMesh configuration is by using a  tag in your FTL view. The default SiteMesh 3 tag processor will automatically parse these tags and make them available to your decorator using a "**meta.**" prefix.

FTL view:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Some title</title>
    <meta name="heading" content="My page heading">
    ...
  </head>
  <body>
    ...
  </body>
</html>
```

Then in your decorator:

```
<html>
  ...
  <div id="content">
    <div id="contentHeading"><sitemesh:write property="meta.heading"/></div>
    ....
  </div>
  ...
```